# Let $S_1$ be a square of unit area. A circle $C_1$ is inscribed in $S_1$ a square $S_2$ is inscribed in $C_2$ and so on....

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Problem :

Let $S_1$ be a square of unit area. A circle $C_1$ is inscribed in $S_1$ a square $S_2$ is inscribed in $C_2$ and so on. In general a circle $C_n$ is inscribed in the square $S_n$ and then a square $S_{n+1}$ is inscribed in the circle $C_n$ Let $a_n$ denote the sum of the areas of the circles $C_1 ,C_2.....C_n$ Then $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is

(a) $\frac{\pi}{2}$

(b) $\frac{\pi}{4}$

(c)$\frac{\pi}{6}$

(d) $\frac{\pi}{3}$ [ Ans. a ]

Please suggest how to solve this problem and I am not getting any clue.. I got this problem on www.mathstudy.in

Comment: Typo first line. You want $S_2$ is inscribed in $C_1$. For solving, find the area of $C_2$. You will likely see what the areas of $C_3$, $C_4$, $\dots$ must be. The areas form an infinite geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_n$ be the radius of $C_n$ and let $x_n$ be the edge length of $S_n$. Then, we have

$$r_1=\frac{1}{2},x_1=1, r_n=\frac 12x_n, x_{n+1}=\sqrt 2r_n.$$
Hence, $$r_{n+1}=\frac 12 x_{n+1}=\frac 12\cdot \sqrt 2r_n=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}r_n.$$
Hence, what you want is 
$$\pi\left\{\left(\frac 12\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\cdots\right\}=\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots\right)=\pi\cdot\frac{1/4}{1-(1/2)}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$